# ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid error when SelectLayerByAttribute run in Python 2.7

Tags: arcpy, python-2.7, select-by-attribute, python-3, error-000840

I am running a line of code in a Python 2.7 environment using `arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management`:

```
fl_haz_selects = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(S_Fld_Haz_Ar, "NEW_SELECTION", "\"DFIRM_ID\" = '{}'".format(fipC))
```

It runs perfectly fine in Python 3.6. Now I am getting the following errors. What am I doing incorrectly here? Note: `S_FLD_Haz_Ar` is a shapefile. Do I just need to make it into a layer? I am trying to avoid making a physical layer.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line
>   3, in    File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 7713, in
>   SelectLayerByAttribute
>       raise e ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. The value cannot be a feature class ERROR 000840: The value is not a
>   Raster Layer. ERROR 000840: The value is not a Mosaic Layer. Failed to
>   execute (SelectLayerByAttribute).

Comment: You need to create a layer from the shapefile before doing selection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `MakeFeatureLayer_management` to make a layer from your shapefile.  (This layer will be saved in memory, so you won't actually be saving a layer file anywhere, and it will be deleted when the application exits.)  Then pass that layer to SelectLayerByAttribute_management:

```
featureLayer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(S_Fld_Haz_Ar, "featureLayer")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(featureLayer, "NEW_SELECTION", "\"DFIRM_ID\" = '{}'".format(fipC))
```

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-feature-layer.htm

Comment: Note, you can also pass the layer by whatever it was named in the MakeFeatureLayer line. e.g. `arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(S_Fld_Haz_Ar, "myLayer") \n arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("myLayer", "NEW_SELECTION", "\"DFIRM_ID\" = '{}'".format(fipC))`

Comment: I am baffled that my old method works fine in 3.6 and 2.7, but I actually came up with a completely easier method that selects the desired records and makes the layer, circumventing the need for the select. By doing `fl_haz_selects = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(S_Fld_Haz_Ar, "fl_haz_lyr", "DFIRM_ID = '{}'".format(fipC))` (I didn't even need to use "\"\ in my field name), I was able to make a layer out of only the selected features I want (those with `"DFIRM_ID = '{}'".format(fipC))`) and eliminate a line of code.

Comment: For ArcGIS Pro and Python 3.x esri has decided to allow featureclasses to be used as input for SelectLayerByAttribute.
http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/select-layer-by-attribute.htm